# Refactoring common code in responses section

Tags: raml

I have some common RAML code that comes up in the `responses` section:

```
/foo
    post:
        responses:
            400:
                common_stuff
            401:
                common_stuff
```

I'd like to refactor this with traits, but I run into the problem that you can't use a parameter to name a node:

```
# Does not work
responses:
    <<code>>:
        common_stuff
```

I can create a trait file which includes the common code

```
#%RAML 1.0 Trait

body: 
  common_stuff
```

But then when I create a trait file for (say) response code 400 I can't figure out how to graft the common_stuff trait into it.

I tried creating a library file like this:

```
#%RAML 1.0 Library
usage: blah

traits:
  body: 
    application/json:
      common_stuff
```

But I get told `Unknown node: 'application/json'`.

So what is the right way of doing this?